# package-private @Configuration bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Where does it matter to use public access modifier on configuration class? Where can I narrow scope to package-private? I noticed that for example in class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter e.g.

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfigurationTest extends  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) 
    ...
```

it doesn't matter. So where does it matter?

Comment: I mean more generally. You can for example have package-private bean created by annotating class as @Service. Then autowired in e.g. some facade and it will work if in the same package